# Is there any way to print the first line from a text file, then loop and print the second, then loop and print the third etc?

Tags: python, loops

Is there any way to import a print the first line from a .txt file, then loop and print the second, then loop and print the third, etc? I already know how to import the data from the text files.

Comment: Please show your code.   If you can import it you can print it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a file named "abc.txt" in the same folder as the python script file. Then you can iterate over them, using:

```
with open('abc.txt') as fp:
  for line in fp:
    print(line.strip())
```

`strip` method is to remove additional newline at the end of each line

Do see the `open` built-in function in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: You don't even need the `.readlines()`; you can use `for ele in fp:`

Comment: Thanks @sabik for the info.

Comment: You can also keep the newline in the original example, and suppress the one generated by print (in 3.0) by using:  `print (line,end='')`

Comment: But this doesn't loop and print the next line. it prints them all at the same time.

Comment: @Khushc The `for` inside the `with` block loops over each line of the file

Comment: I was trying to get it to print one line only then loop back and print the line beneath etc.

Comment: `fp.readlines()` will return a list of lines. Then you can access them using index to do that